# MongoDB insert \u0000 after each character in string field?

Tags: mongodb

I am just started mongodb and facing issue when saving XML in string field. it add '\u0000' with each character in xml file. like

"\u0000?\u0000x\u0000m\u0000l\u0000 \u0000v\u0000e\u0000r\u0000s\u0000i\u0000o\u0000n

I need to save this XML as it is without JSON 0r BSON conversion in string field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till the time, I found a query to get xml back in correct format.

```
db.Test.find({"data":"XYZ"}).forEach(function(doc){
         var xml = doc.data.replace(/\u0000/g,"");
         print(xml);
})
```